# Using StartTLS with LDAP from System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, starttls

I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server which requires StartTLS, but having no luck - whenever I use either the SessionOptions.StartTransportLayerSecurity(..) or set SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer to true, I get exceptions.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
using (var connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(config.LdapServer, config.Port, false, false)))
{
    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(config.BindDN, config.BindPassword);
    connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += (conn, cert) => {return true;};
    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    //connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    connection.SessionOptions.StartTransportLayerSecurity(null); // throws here, same if done after bind.
    connection.Bind();

    ... do stuff with connection
}
```

The resulting exception is "TlsOperationException: An unspecified error occurred", which happens when invoking the StartTransportLayerSecurity method.

I've tested the code against both and OpenLDAP server and Active Directory, but neither works.

Does anyone know how to get StartTLS working with System.DirectoryServices?

Comment: Could you please specify the specific versions of OpenLDAP, Active Directory and especially the operating systems for *both* client and server involved here to narrow down the scope? There used to be a fair amount of subtle LDAP stack incompatibilities in the wild, which could still apply to the potentially legacy scenario your customer might be using.

Comment: Hi Steffen, info was OpenLDAP 2.4.18, FreeBSD for server and client was a Windows Server 2008 r2 machine (client code is hosted in an ASP.Net application, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1).

Searching a bit further on the version of LDAP led me to some blog posts on the topic including: 

http://pongo15.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/on-getting-openldap-and-windows-ldap-to-interop/ - which helped me get to the bottom of the issue.

I'm going to try and encourage user to move up to latest OpenLDAP as I assume this issue is probably fixed in later versions (their version is really old, released Sun, 6 Sep 2009)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up information, which will help later readers regarding issues like this (+1)! I've [updated my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9020311/revisions#) accordingly …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more work on this issue I found that I was running up against a couple of issues:

1. There was a bug in the code where the port number was being incorrectly changed to the SSL port (636) when connecting to AD in our test suite (doh!).
2. The OpenLDAP test server (that was a replica of our customers) was using openldap-2.4.18 - which has known issues with StartTLS.

After applying a patch to OpenLDAP (as discussed here - http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/200405/msg00096.html) we were able to fix #2 - at which point we started getting a different error "A local error occurred".

Though originally we had this code:

```
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate 
    += (conn, cert) => {return true;};
```

We had removed it while testing, and because the OpenLDAP server was using a self-signed cert, that was not in a trusted store.  Re-introducing that callback resolved this issue, though we now make it a configurable option i.e. "Verify Server Certificate Y/N" so customers need to opt into skipping the check (mostly for our QA team to use).

Thanks Steffen for pointing me in the direction of OpenLDAP versions which lead me to this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed summary of your findings (+1) - I've learned something as well, namely to post my research results as an answer immediately in order to avoid duplicated efforts (after all, answers can be refined anytime), and to make researching interesting issues with generous bounties like yours more worthwhile even! I've [expanded my comment as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9020311/45773) now accordingly to get acquainted with this approach - thanks much ;)

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a fair amount of subtle LDAP stack incompatibilities in the wild, which could still apply to the potentially legacy scenario your customer might be using.

The following are the most commonly encountered issues regarding incompatibilities between OpenLDAP and Microsoft's LDAP stack <strike>(I'll amend and/or replace these links once more info is available)</strike>:

- The OpenLDAP [StartTLS issues (ITS#3037)](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/200405/msg00096.html) (summarized in [On getting OpenLDAP and Windows LDAP to interop](http://pongo15.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/on-getting-openldap-and-windows-ldap-to-interop/)) have triggered a respective hotfix:

  - [You cannot send Start TLS requests from a computer that is running Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP or Windows Vista to a server that is running OpenLDAP Software](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959873/)
- [An extended operation that is sent to an LDAP server by API over the LDAP service causes a protocol error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841461/)

Obviously, updating either OpenLDAP and/or Windows (ideally both of course) should remedy these issues, if they turn out to be the culprit here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Please read this topic:
[Binding over a TLS/SSL Encrypted Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic6_binding)

Example 19. Binding to an ADAM instance on secure port 50001 using Basic authentication and SSL/TLS

```
string hostNameAndSSLPort = "sea-dc-02.fabrikam.com:50001";
string userName = "cn=User1,cn=AdamUsers,cn=ap1,dc=fabrikam,dc=com";
string password = "adamPassword01!";

// establish a connection
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(hostNameAndSSLPort);

// create an LdapSessionOptions object to configure session 
// settings on the connection.
LdapSessionOptions options = connection.SessionOptions;

options.ProtocolVersion = 3;

options.SecureSocketLayer = true;

connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

NetworkCredential credential =
        new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

connection.Credential = credential;

try
{
    connection.Bind();
    Console.WriteLine("\nUser account {0} validated using " +
        "ssl.", userName);

    if (options.SecureSocketLayer == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SSL for encryption is enabled\nSSL information:\n" +
        "\tcipher strength: {0}\n" +
        "\texchange strength: {1}\n" +
        "\tprotocol: {2}\n" +
        "\thash strength: {3}\n" +
        "\talgorithm: {4}\n",
        options.SslInformation.CipherStrength,
        options.SslInformation.ExchangeStrength,
        options.SslInformation.Protocol,
        options.SslInformation.HashStrength,
        options.SslInformation.AlgorithmIdentifier);
    }

}
catch (LdapException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCredential validation for User " +
        "account {0} using ssl failed\n" +
        "LdapException: {1}", userName, e.Message);
}
catch (DirectoryOperationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCredential validation for User " +
    "account {0} using ssl failed\n" +
    "DirectoryOperationException: {1}", userName, e.Message);
}
```

And the next example show "How to use TLS to authenticate and perform a task"

```
string hostOrDomainName = "fabrikam.com";
string userName = "user1";
string password = "password1";

// establish a connection to the directory
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(hostOrDomainName);

NetworkCredential credential =
    new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName);

connection.Credential = credential;

connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

LdapSessionOptions options = connection.SessionOptions;

options.ProtocolVersion = 3;

try
{
    options.StartTransportLayerSecurity(null);
    Console.WriteLine("TLS started.\n");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start TLS failed with {0}", 
        e.Message);
    return;
}

try
{
    connection.Bind();
    Console.WriteLine("Bind succeeded using basic " +
        "authentication and SSL.\n");

    Console.WriteLine("Complete another task over " +
        "this SSL connection");
    TestTask(hostName);
}
catch (LdapException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

try
{
    options.StopTransportLayerSecurity();
    Console.WriteLine("Stop TLS succeeded\n");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop TLS failed with {0}", e.Message);
}

 Console.WriteLine("Switching to negotiate auth type");
 connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;

 Console.WriteLine("\nRe-binding to the directory");
 connection.Bind();

// complete some action over this non-SSL connection
// note, because Negotiate was used, the bind request 
// is secure. 
// run a task using this new binding
TestTask(hostName);
```